# ORACLE SQL DEV | Select only one duplicate row having the highest value

Tags: duplicates, max, oracle-sqldeveloper

quick question about something i'm not able to find the answer.

The objective of my SQL request is to find the last holder from a cemetery emplacement by emplacement.

For example:

| ID_CARTO_EMPL | ID_EXT | LAST_HOLDER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| N¿A1¿10¿¿¿¿1¿ | 55706 | VIK TOR |
| N¿A1¿10¿¿¿¿11¿ | 52536 | MARC MINI |
| N¿A1¿10¿¿¿¿11¿ | 52458 | DAVID MARCEL |
| (41 000 rows left) | (41 000 rows left) | (41 000 rows left) |

As you can see the column "ID_CARTO_EMPL" got a duplicate rows. (N¿A1¿10¿¿¿¿11¿)
So in this case I want to select the one who has the most higher value in the column "ID_EXT" (52536)

Going from this :

| ID_CARTO_EMPL | ID_EXT | LAST_HOLDER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| N¿A1¿10¿¿¿¿1¿ | 55706 | VIK TOR |
| N¿A1¿10¿¿¿¿11¿ | 52536 | MARC MINI |
| N¿A1¿10¿¿¿¿11¿ | 52458 | DAVID MARCEL |
| (41 000 rows left) | (41 000 rows left) | (41 000 rows left) |

To this:

| ID_CARTO_EMPL | ID_EXT | LAST_HOLDER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| N¿A1¿10¿¿¿¿1¿ | 55706 | VIK TOR |
| N¿A1¿10¿¿¿¿11¿ | 52536 | MARC MINI |
| (41 000 rows left) | (41 000 rows left) | (41 000 rows left) |

I want to do this for more than 41 000 rows looking for duplicate and if we got one select only the one with the higher value in "ID_EXT" column.

There is my code for the moment:

```
--Objective, to obtain the last holder of the concession in order to
-- to conduct research
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Start of the script

SELECT

-- Concatenation in order to get the cleanest ID_CARTO_EMPL possible
(et_empl.cd_cim_empl ||'¤'|| et_empl.cle1_empl ||'¤'|| et_empl.cle2_empl||'¤'||
et_empl.cle3_empl||'¤'||et_empl.cle4_empl||'¤'||et_empl.cle5_empl||'¤'||
et_empl.tombe_empl||'¤'||et_empl.compl_empl) AS ID_CARTO_EMPL,

-------------------------------------------------------------
et_co.cd_c,

et_conc_pers.cd_e,

et_conc_pers.cd_status

et_conc_pers.id_ext,
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Get the dealer of the concession (concatenation N/P/NJF)
(et_perssup.name_e || ' ' || et_perssup.pren_e || ' ' || et_perssup.name_jf_e)
AS LAST_HOLDER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- From the location table (base table)
FROM and_empl
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Join
INNER JOIN et_co ON et_empl.cd_c = et_co.cd_c
INNER JOIN et_conc_pers ON et_empl.cd_c = et_conc_pers.cd_c
INNER JOIN et_perssup ON et_conc_pers.cd_e = et_perssup.cd_e
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WHERE
et_conc_pers.cd_status_pers_conc = 2
AND et_empl.histo_empl = 0
AND et_empl.cd_cim_empl = 'N'

ORDER BY ID_CARTO_EMPL ASC
```

---

Regarding about multiples conditions for the request, I figured out the sql query but the one I wanted to do at first seems more complex than that.
Overall I had to split my request into 3:

-1: location owner
-2: Last holder
-3: Last deceased

So on one line I want: "ID_CARTO_EMPL" | "location owner" | "Last Holder" | "Last deceased"

Objectif example :

| ID_CARTO_EMPL | ID_EXT | LOCATION_OWNER | LAST_HOLDER | LAST_DECEASED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| N¿A1¿10¿¿¿¿1¿ | 55706 | VIK TOR |  | HUGO TOR |
| N¿A1¿10¿¿¿¿11¿ | 52536 | MARC MINI | DAVID MINI | BERNADETTE MINI |
| (41 000 rows left) | (41 000 rows left) | (41 000 rows left) | (41 000 rows left) | (41 000 rows left) |

So for each row i need to find this :

```
LOCATION_OWNER : "STATUT" = 1
LAST_HOLDER : "STATUT" = 2 AND HIGHEST "ID_EXT"
LAST_DECEASED : "STATUT" = 13 AND HIGHEST "ID_EXT"
```

I succeeded with three queries but not just one:

LOCATION_OWNER :

```
--Objective, to obtain most of the information present in the table
-- ET_CARTO_EMPL with only the dealer as person.
-------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------
--Start of script

SELECT DISTINCT

-- Obtain CLE_EMPL
et_empl.key_empl,

-- Concatenation in order to obtain the cleanest possible ID_CARTO_EMPL
-- Join field
(et_empl.cd_cim_empl ||'¤'|| et_empl.cle1_empl ||'¤'|| et_empl.cle2_empl||'¤'||
et_empl.cle3_empl||'¤'||et_empl.cle4_empl||'¤'||et_empl.cle5_empl||'¤'||
et_empl.tombe_empl||'¤'||et_empl.compl_empl) AS ID_CARTO_EMPL,

-- Obtain the Title number of the concession
et_co.numtit_c AS NUM_TITRE,

-- Obtain the Concession number of the concession
et_co.num_conc_c AS NUM_CONCESSION,

-- Obtain the expiration date of the concession
et_co.dt_exp_c AS DATE_DEADLINE,

-- Get dealership location type
et_empl.type_c,

-- Get dealership from dealership (concatenation N/P/NJF)
(et_perssup.nom_e || ' ' || et_perssup.pren_e || ' ' || et_perssup.nom_jf_e)
AS DEALER
-------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------
-- From the locations table (base table)
FROM and_empl
-------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------
-- Join
INNER JOIN et_co ON et_empl.cd_c = et_co.cd_c
INNER JOIN et_conc_pers ON et_empl.cd_c = et_conc_pers.cd_c
INNER JOIN et_perssup ON et_conc_pers.cd_e = et_perssup.cd_e
-------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------
--Terms
WHERE
et_conc_pers.cd_statut_pers_conc = 1 AND et_empl.histo_empl = 0
```

LAST_HOLDER :

```
-- Objective, obtain the last holder of the concession
-------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------
-- Start of script
WITH
   your_query
   AS
      (SELECT -- Concatenation to obtain the cleanest possible ID_CARTO_EMPL
              ( et_empl.cd_cim_empl
               || '¤'
               || et_empl.key1_empl
               || '¤'
               || et_empl.key2_empl
               || '¤'
               || et_empl.key3_empl
               || '¤'
               || et_empl.key4_empl
               || '¤'
               || et_empl.key5_empl
               || '¤'
               || et_empl.grave_empl
               || '¤'
               || et_empl.compl_empl) AS ID_CARTO_EMPL,
              -------------------------------------------------- -----------
              et_conc_pers.id_ext, -- Mandatory otherwise the query crashes
              -------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------
              -- Obtain the last concession holder (N/P/NJF concatenation)
              ( et_perssup.nom_e
               || ' '
               || et_perssup.pren_e
               || ' '
               || et_perssup.nom_jf_e) AS LAST_HOLDER
         -------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------
         -- From the location table (base table)
         FROM and_empl
              -------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------
              -- Join
              INNER JOIN et_co ON et_empl.cd_c = et_co.cd_c
              INNER JOIN et_conc_pers ON et_empl.cd_c = et_conc_pers.cd_c
              INNER JOIN et_perssup ON et_conc_pers.cd_e = et_perssup.cd_e
        -------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------
        -- Terms
        WHERE et_conc_pers.cd_statut_pers_conc = 2
              AND et_empl.histo_empl = 0),
   time
   AS
      (SELECT ID_CARTO_EMPL,
              id_ext,
              LAST_HOLDER,
              ROW_NUMBER()
                 OVER (PARTITION BY ID_CARTO_EMPL ORDER BY id_ext DESC) rn
         FROM your_query)
  SELECT ID_CARTO_EMPL, id_ext, LAST_HOLDER
    FROM temp
   WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY ID_CARTO_EMPL ASC
```

LAST_DECEASED:

```
-- Objective, obtain the last buried of the concession
-------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------
-- Start of script
 
WITH
   your_query
   AS
      (SELECT -- Concatenation to obtain the cleanest possible ID_CARTO_EMPL
              ( et_empl.cd_cim_empl
               || '¤'
               || et_empl.key1_empl
               || '¤'
               || et_empl.key2_empl
               || '¤'
               || et_empl.key3_empl
               || '¤'
               || et_empl.key4_empl
               || '¤'
               || et_empl.key5_empl
               || '¤'
               || et_empl.grave_empl
               || '¤'
               || et_empl.compl_empl) AS ID_CARTO_EMPL,
              -------------------------------------------------- -----------
              et_conc_pers.id_ext, -- Mandatory otherwise the query crashes
              -------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------
              -- Obtain the last buried of the concession (concatenation N/P/NJF)
              ( et_perssup.nom_e
               || ' '
               || et_perssup.pren_e
               || ' '
               || et_perssup.nom_jf_e) AS LAST_BURIED
         -------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------
         -- From the location table (base table)
         FROM and_empl
         -------------------------------------------------- -----------------------------------
              -- Joints
              INNER JOIN et_co ON et_empl.cd_c = et_co.cd_c
              INNER JOIN et_conc_pers ON et_empl.cd_c = et_conc_pers.cd_c
              INNER JOIN et_perssup ON et_conc_pers.cd_e = et_perssup.cd_e
        -------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------
        -- Terms
        WHERE et_conc_pers.cd_statut_pers_conc = 13
              AND et_empl.histo_empl = 0),
   time
   AS
      (SELECT ID_CARTO_EMPL,
              id_ext,
              LAST_BURIED,
              ROW_NUMBER()
                 OVER (PARTITION BY ID_CARTO_EMPL ORDER BY id_ext DESC) rn
         FROM your_query)
  SELECT ID_CARTO_EMPL, id_ext, LAST_INHUME
    FROM temp
   WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY ID_CARTO_EMPL ASC
```

If it is possible to combine these 3 requests it could be very nice but not major. I continue my research in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, one option is to partition rows by *something* (that seems to be `id_carto_empl` in your case) and sort them in *some order* (in your case, `id_ext` in descending order).

Then, as a final result, return rows that ranked as the "highest" (i.e. have `rn = 1`).

Something like this:

```
with temp as
  (select id_carto_empl, id_ext, last_holder,
     row_number() over (partition by id_carto_empl order by id_ext desc) rn
   from your_table
  )
select id_carto_empl, id_ext, last_holder
from temp
where rn = 1
```

---

Applied to your query:

```
WITH
   your_query
   AS
      (SELECT -- Concatenation in order to get the cleanest ID_CARTO_EMPL possible
              (   et_empl.cd_cim_empl
               || '¤'
               || et_empl.cle1_empl
               || '¤'
               || et_empl.cle2_empl
               || '¤'
               || et_empl.cle3_empl
               || '¤'
               || et_empl.cle4_empl
               || '¤'
               || et_empl.cle5_empl
               || '¤'
               || et_empl.tombe_empl
               || '¤'
               || et_empl.compl_empl) AS id_carto_empl,
              -------------------------------------------------------------
              et_co.cd_c,
              et_conc_pers.cd_e,
              et_conc_pers.cd_status,
              et_conc_pers.id_ext,
              --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              -- Get the dealer of the concession (concatenation N/P/NJF)
              (   et_perssup.name_e
               || ' '
               || et_perssup.pren_e
               || ' '
               || et_perssup.name_jf_e) AS last_holder
         --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         -- From the location table (base table)
         FROM and_empl
              --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              -- Join
              INNER JOIN et_co ON et_empl.cd_c = et_co.cd_c
              INNER JOIN et_conc_pers ON et_empl.cd_c = et_conc_pers.cd_c
              INNER JOIN et_perssup ON et_conc_pers.cd_e = et_perssup.cd_e
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        WHERE     et_conc_pers.cd_status_pers_conc = 2
              AND et_empl.histo_empl = 0
              AND et_empl.cd_cim_empl = 'N'),
   temp
   AS
      (SELECT id_carto_empl,
              id_ext,
              last_holder,
              ROW_NUMBER ()
                 OVER (PARTITION BY id_carto_empl ORDER BY id_ext DESC) rn
         FROM your_table)
  SELECT id_carto_empl, id_ext, last_holder
    FROM temp
   WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY id_carto_empl ASC
```

---

Regarding your comment about "multiple" conditions in the same query: you can do that, using any number of analytic functions that return result you're interested in.

Here's an example based on Scott's sample schema and its `EMP` table. Suppose you want to fetch employees who earn the most AND the ones who are first alphabetically PER each department.

```
SQL> break on deptno
SQL> select deptno, empno, ename, job, sal
  2  from emp
  3  order by deptno, sal desc, ename;

    DEPTNO      EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- ---------- --------- ----------
        10       7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000  --> earns the most in dept. 10
                 7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450  --> alphabetically first in dept. 10
                 7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300
        20       7902 FORD       ANALYST         3000  --> Ford and Scott earn
                 7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         3000  --> the most in dept. 20
                 7566 JONES      MANAGER         2975
                 7876 ADAMS      CLERK           1100  --> alphabetically first in dept. 20
                 7369 SMITH      CLERK            800
        30       7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         2850
                 7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        1600
                 7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        1500
                 7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        1250
                 7521 WARD       SALESMAN        1250
                 7900 JAMES      CLERK            950

14 rows selected.
```

Query you'd then use might be this:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select deptno, empno, ename, job, sal,
  3            rank() over (partition by deptno order by sal desc) rnk_sal_desc,
  4            row_number() over (partition by deptno order by ename asc) rn_ename_asc
  5     from emp
  6    )
  7  select deptno, empno, ename, job, sal
  8  from temp
  9  where 1 in (rnk_sal_desc, rn_ename_asc)
 10  order by deptno, sal desc, empno asc;

    DEPTNO      EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- ---------- --------- ----------
        10       7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000
                 7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
        20       7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         3000
                 7902 FORD       ANALYST         3000
                 7876 ADAMS      CLERK           1100
        30       7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         2850
                 7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        1600

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Very well ! Many thanks to you @Littlefoot, it works fine. The next step is to see why it works :)
At first I wanted to make the concessionaire, the last holder and the last buried in the same request but I think it's too complicated or even impossible.

Comment: What you wanted *at first* is possible in the same query and it isn't too complicated; it is, actually, rather simple. I edited the answer and posted an example which shows how to do it; apply it to your data.

Comment: I edited my question because what i wanted to do at first seem more complex than what you propose here.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the MAX function.

Stripping it down to its basic skeleton, and avoiding all the concatenation and composition, you're looking at something like

```
SELECT id_carto_empl, MAX(id_ext) FROM my_theoretical_emplacement_table;
```

If you rebuild some of your joins and concatenations within that (substitute your expression for id_carto_empl and build the necessary joins for the "my_theoretical_emplacement_table"), this will give you a list of emplacement IDs with the highest related ID alongside.

You can then use another select or join to get the name associated with the id_ext and build a single output of id_carto_empl, id_ext, last_holder